# Rails, Uninitialized constant after rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the book: "Rails, Angular, Postgres and Bootstrap". At some point, the author wrote a new migration, with this code:

```
class AddAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :states do |t|
      t.string :code, size: 2, null: false
      t.string :name,          null: false
    end

    create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.string     :street,                    null: false
      t.string     :city,                      null: false
      t.references :state,                     null: false
      t.string     :zipcode,                   null: false
    end

    create_table :customers_billing_addresses do |t|
      t.references :customer, null: false
      t.references :address,  null: false
    end

    create_table :customers_shipping_addresses do |t|
      t.references :customer, null: false
      t.references :address,  null: false
      t.boolean :primary, null: false, default: false
    end
  end
end
```

Here is what I did:

1. `rails g migration add-addresses`
2. Copied and pasted the code above in the generated migration-file
3. `rake db:migrate`

This happens:

```
== 20161211174928 AddAddresses: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:states)
   -> 0.0140s
-- create_table(:addresses)
   -> 0.0129s
-- create_table(:customers_billing_addresses)
   -> 0.0115s
-- create_table(:customers_shipping_addresses)
   -> 0.0142s
== 20161211174928 AddAddresses: migrated (0.0529s) ============================
```

4. `rails c`
5. `State.last` causes this:

   `NameError: uninitialized constant State`
6. I checked, whether 'State' was around:

   ```
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map do |model|  
     model.capitalize.singularize.camelize
   end
   ```

leads to:

```
["SchemaMigration", "ArInternalMetadatum", "User", "Customer", "State", "Address", "CustomersBillingAddress", "CustomersShippingAddress"]
```

Since 'State' is clearly there, I'm clueless what the problem is. Any suggestions?

PS: I already tried this, but the problem remains:

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a `state.rb` file under `app/models` directory? I guess you don't. Creating a table will not generate the `model`(class) while generating the model using `rails g model` will create the migration for you.

Create a file called `state.rb` in `app/models` and add the following contents to the file.

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: But why on earth is the author of the book not telling that? Thank you

Comment: I have no idea about that book. Are you sure you followed everything in the book?

Comment: He actually does reference an earlier page in the book, where he did this: rails g model customer first_name:string \
last_name:string \
email:string \
username:string. But was that really too much to just write it down? Thank you very much

Comment: Ah! Looks like the author didn't want to spoonfeed. IMO, it is a good thing.

Comment: The author had all this in one file. But for every time, you type in rails g model state" rails automatically adds a migration. It is slightly confusing, since you either need to delete the migrations made by rails or type in the code for each migration. Maybe Im just stupid, but I don't think that it is obvious.

Comment: I see. Don't worry. Be careful going on through the book now on. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicate State.code and State.name cannot be blank, and very likely do not have any data in the table, start by creating some data, i.e.:

```
state = State.create(code: 12, name: "New Jersey")
```

Make a file called state.rb in the models directory. in it put:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and see if that works. Later you can add the associations. This will initialize the class.

Comment: irb(main):006:0> state=State.create(code: 12, name: "New Jersey")
NameError: uninitialized constant State

Comment: Have you created a model for State?

Comment: As far as I know, this should create the model:     create_table :states do |t|
      t.string :code, size: 2, null: false
      t.string :name,          null: false
    end Is that wrong?

Comment: What is the result in the console when you type State.column_names

Comment: Creating the table and creating the model are different steps.  Just put the following in a filed called state.rb